# 3 layers database. How do I relate 3 entities to each other?

Tags: java, foreign-keys, android-room

I have a 3 entities: `Categories`, `Folders` and `Cards`. Each Category can contain Folders where you can contain Cards. I could successfully relate Categories and Folders entities by using ForeignKey it worked perfectly. But when I made Cards entities and tried to relate it with same logic Studio throws me an error. Is there another way to link all this 3? The code of entities are as follows:

```
@Entity(tableName = "categories")   
public class Categories {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@ColumnInfo(name = "category_id")
private int categoryId;

@ColumnInfo(name = "category_name")
private String categoryName;

@Ignore
public Categories() {
}
```

Folders

```
@Entity(tableName = "folders", foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = Categories.class,
    parentColumns = "category_id", childColumns = "current_category_id", onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE))     
public class Folders {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@ColumnInfo(name = "folder_id")
private int folderId = 0;

@ColumnInfo(name = "folder_name")
private String folderName;

@ColumnInfo(name = "current_category_id")
private int categoryId;
```

Cards

```
@Entity(tableName = "cards",foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = Folders.class,
    parentColumns = "folder_id", childColumns = "current_folder_id", onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE))
public class Cards {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@ColumnInfo(name = "card_id")
private int cardId = 0;

@ColumnInfo(name = "card_name")
private String cardName;

@ColumnInfo(name = "card_value")
private String cardValue;

@ColumnInfo(name = "current_folder_id")
private int folderId;

@Ignore
public Cards() {
}
```

Comment: "throws me an error" is not very helpful. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)  For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular-formatted base table initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete what you are attempting you could use :-

```
@Entity(tableName = "cards",foreignKeys = {
        @ForeignKey(entity = Folders.class, parentColumns = "folder_id", childColumns = "current_folder_id", onDelete = CASCADE),
        @ForeignKey(entity = Categories.class, parentColumns = "category_id", childColumns = "current_category_id", onDelete = CASCADE)})
public class Cards {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "card_id")
    private int cardId = 0;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "card_name")
    private String cardName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "card_value")
    private String cardValue;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "current_folder_id")
    private int folderId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "current_category_id") /*<<<<<<<<<< ADDED column */
    private int category_id;

    @Ignore
    public Cards() {
    }
}
```

**However** as **Folders** is a child of **Categories** then the link from Cards to Categories is implicit (i.e. A Folder must have a Categories row as a parent) the following should suffice (and doesn't have an unnecessary column) :-

```
@Entity(tableName = "cards",foreignKeys = {
        @ForeignKey(entity = Folders.class, parentColumns = "folder_id", childColumns = "current_folder_id", onDelete = CASCADE)})
public class Cards {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "card_id")
    private int cardId = 0;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "card_name")
    private String cardName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "card_value")
    private String cardValue;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "current_folder_id")
    private int folderId;

    @Ignore
    public Cards() {
    }
}
```

---

## Example

The following basic App is based upon your code and the 2nd answer. It builds a deck of playing cards.

Categories reflecting suits Hearts, Spades.... *(note that some idiot accidentally (on purpose) introduced a suit name ooops so 65 cards in the pack)*

Folders being either court cards or normal cards (2-10) each card having the face value.

It then outputs every card's information (name, value, id, folder and category(suit)) to the log.

### The Code

**Categories.java**

```
@Entity(tableName = "categories")
public class Categories {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "category_id")
    private int categoryId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "category_name")
    private String categoryName;

    public Categories() {
    }

    @Ignore
    public Categories(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public int getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(int categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }
}
```

**Folders.java**

```
@Entity(tableName = "folders", foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = Categories.class,
        parentColumns = "category_id", childColumns = "current_category_id", onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE))
public class Folders {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "folder_id")
    private int folderId = 0;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "folder_name")
    private String folderName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "current_category_id")
    private int categoryId;

    public Folders() {}

    @Ignore
    public Folders(int categoryId, String folderName) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
        this.folderName = folderName;
    }

    public int getFolderId() {
        return folderId;
    }

    public void setFolderId(int folderId) {
        this.folderId = folderId;
    }

    public String getFolderName() {
        return folderName;
    }

    public void setFolderName(String folderName) {
        this.folderName = folderName;
    }

    public int getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(int categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    public Categories getOwningCategories(GamesDatabase gdb) {
        return gdb.getGamesDBDao().getACategoriesRowById(this.categoryId);
    }
}
```

- Note the **`getOwningCategories`** method (**GamesDatabase** is the @Database class and getGaMesDao the method within that access the @Dao's (all in the one file **GamesDao.java**))

**Cards.java**

```
@Entity(tableName = "cards",foreignKeys = {
        @ForeignKey(entity = Folders.class, parentColumns = "folder_id", childColumns = "current_folder_id", onDelete = CASCADE)})
public class Cards {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "card_id")
    private int cardId = 0;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "card_name")
    private String cardName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "card_value")
    private String cardValue;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "current_folder_id")
    private int folderId;

    public Cards() {}

    @Ignore
    public Cards(String cardName, String cardValue, int folderId) {
        this.cardName = cardName;
        this.cardValue = cardValue;
        this.folderId = folderId;
    }

    public Folders getOwningFolders(GamesDatabase gdb) {
        return gdb.getGamesDBDao().getAFoldersRowById(folderId);
    }

    public Categories getOwningCategories(GamesDatabase gdb) {
        return gdb.getGamesDBDao().getACategoriesRowById(getOwningFolders(gdb).getCategoryId());
    }

    public int getCardId() {
        return cardId;
    }

    public void setCardId(int cardId) {
        this.cardId = cardId;
    }

    public String getCardName() {
        return cardName;
    }

    public void setCardName(String cardName) {
        this.cardName = cardName;
    }

    public String getCardValue() {
        return cardValue;
    }

    public void setCardValue(String cardValue) {
        this.cardValue = cardValue;
    }

    public int getFolderId() {
        return folderId;
    }

    public void setFolderId(int folderId) {
        this.folderId = folderId;
    }
}
```

- Again note the **getOwning???** methods.

**GamesDao.java**

```
@Dao
public interface GamesDao {

    @Insert()
    long[] insertCategoriesRows(Categories... categories);

    @Insert()
    long insertCategoriesRow(Categories categories);

    @Insert()
    long[] insertFoldersRows(Folders... folders);

    @Insert()
    long insertFoldersRow(Folders folders);

    @Insert
    long[] insertCardsRows(Cards... cards);

    @Insert()
    long insertCardsRow(Cards cards);

    @Delete()
    int deleteManyCategoriesRows(Categories... categories);

    @Delete()
    int deleteACategoriesRow(Categories categories);

    @Delete()
    int deleteManyFoldersRows(Folders... folders);

    @Delete()
    int deleteAFolders(Folders folders);

    @Delete()
    int deleteManyCardsRows(Cards... cards);

    @Delete()
    int deleteACardRow(Cards cards);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM categories")
    Categories[] getAllCategoriesRows();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM folders")
    Folders[] getAllFoldersRows();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM cards")
    Cards[] getAllCards();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE category_id = :id")
    Categories getACategoriesRowById(int id);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM folders WHERE folder_id = :id")
    Folders getAFoldersRowById(int id);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM cards WHERE card_id = :id")
    Cards getACardsRowById(int id);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM folders WHERE current_category_id = :id")
    Folders[] getFoldersPerCategoriesId(int id);
}
```

- note the **getFoldresPerCategories** method

**GamesDatabase.java**

```
@Database(version = 1,exportSchema = true, entities = {Categories.class,Folders.class,Cards.class})
public abstract class GamesDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public static final String DBNAME = "games";

    public abstract GamesDao getGamesDBDao();
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GamesDatabase mGamesDB;
    GamesDao mGamesDao;
    private static final String[] card_suits = new String[]{"Spades","Hearts","Clubs","Diamonds","ooops"};
    private static final String[] courtcard_values = new String[]{
            "Jack","Queen","King","Ace"
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mGamesDB = Room.databaseBuilder(this,GamesDatabase.class,GamesDatabase.DBNAME)
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();

        // Suits
        mGamesDao = mGamesDB.getGamesDBDao();
        for (String s: card_suits) {
            mGamesDao.insertCategoriesRow(new Categories(s));
        }

        for (Categories c: mGamesDao.getAllCategoriesRows()) {
            mGamesDao.insertFoldersRow(new Folders(c.getCategoryId(),"CourtCards"));
            mGamesDao.insertFoldersRow(new Folders(c.getCategoryId(),"NormalCards"));
            for (Folders f: mGamesDao.getFoldersPerCategoriesId(c.getCategoryId())) {
                if (f.getFolderName().equals("CourtCards")) {
                    for (String s: courtcard_values) {
                        mGamesDao.insertCardsRow(new Cards(s,getCourtCardValueFromName(s),f.getFolderId()));
                    }
                } else {
                    for (int i=2; i < 11; i++) {
                        mGamesDao.insertCardsRow(new Cards(String.valueOf(i),String.valueOf(i),f.getFolderId()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (Cards card: mGamesDao.getAllCards()) {
            logCardsInfo(card);
        }

        mGamesDB.close();
    }

    private String getCourtCardValueFromName(String courtCardName) {
        int basevalue = 11;
        for (String s: courtcard_values) {
            if (s.equals(courtCardName)) {
                return String.valueOf(basevalue);
            }
            basevalue++;
            if (basevalue > 13) basevalue = 1;
        }
        return "UNKNOWN";
    }

    private void logCardsInfo(Cards card) {
        Log.d("CARDINFO",
                "Card Name is " + card.getCardName() +
                        "\n\tValue is " + card.getCardValue() +
                        "\n\tCardID is " + card.getCardId() +
                        "\n\tIn Folder " + card.getOwningFolders(mGamesDB).getFolderName() +
                        "\n\t\tIn Category " + card.getOwningCategories(mGamesDB).getCategoryName()
        );
    }
}
```

- **Note** for convenience **`allowMainThreadQueries()`** has been used.

### Result

```
2019-09-16 08:58:23.530 17468-17468/aso.so57943963foreignkeys D/CARDINFO: Card Name is Jack
        Value is 11
        CardID is 1
        In Folder CourtCards
            In Category Spades
2019-09-16 08:58:23.534 17468-17468/aso.so57943963foreignkeys D/CARDINFO: Card Name is Queen
        Value is 12
        CardID is 2
        In Folder CourtCards
            In Category Spades
2019-09-16 08:58:23.538 17468-17468/aso.so57943963foreignkeys D/CARDINFO: Card Name is King
        Value is 13
        CardID is 3
        In Folder CourtCards
            In Category Spades
2019-09-16 08:58:23.546 17468-17468/aso.so57943963foreignkeys D/CARDINFO: Card Name is Ace
        Value is 1
        CardID is 4
        In Folder CourtCards
            In Category Spades
2019-09-16 08:58:23.553 17468-17468/aso.so57943963foreignkeys D/CARDINFO: Card Name is 2
        Value is 2
        CardID is 5
        In Folder NormalCards
            In Category Spades
2019-09-16 08:58:23.559 17468-17468/aso.so57943963foreignkeys D/CARDINFO: Card Name is 3
        Value is 3
        CardID is 6
        In Folder NormalCards
            In Category Spades
```

.........

```
2019-09-16 08:58:23.822 17468-17468/aso.so57943963foreignkeys D/CARDINFO: Card Name is 8
        Value is 8
        CardID is 63
        In Folder NormalCards
            In Category ooops
2019-09-16 08:58:23.826 17468-17468/aso.so57943963foreignkeys D/CARDINFO: Card Name is 9
        Value is 9
        CardID is 64
        In Folder NormalCards
            In Category ooops
2019-09-16 08:58:23.832 17468-17468/aso.so57943963foreignkeys D/CARDINFO: Card Name is 10
        Value is 10
        CardID is 65
        In Folder NormalCards
            In Category ooops
```